# Can I install an outlet on a freestanding pillar platform?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Example: could I take 4 pyramid deck blocks and cover with 2x12 pressure treated on edge, pour gravel in that and cover with 2x12, this then would be a solid platform for mounting the outlet.  Alternately 6x6's tied together.  Harder to work with 6x6 as stores can't cut.

This is because I can't dig down in this area due to soil compaction and multiple utility lines underneath.

314.23 Supports.
(B) Structural Mounting. An enclosure supported from a structural member of a building or from grade shall be rigidly supported either directly or by using a metal, polymeric, or wood brace.

(2) Braces. Metal braces shall be protected against corrosion and formed from metal that is not less than 0.51 mm (0.020 in.) thick uncoated. Wood braces shall have a cross section not less than nominal 25 mm × 50 mm (1 in. × 2 in.). Wood braces in wet locations shall be treated for the conditions. Polymeric braces shall be identified as being suitable for the use.

[What NEC requirements apply to installing receptacle next to a tree?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26815/what-nec-requirements-apply-to-installing-receptacle-next-to-a-tree)

Comment: Can you post a diagram of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Diagram may have to wait until later or tomorrow off work time.  I am considering running sch 80 conduit above ground and need something to attach an outlet to above ground.  I can not pound a stake in due to underground propane, electrical and water in the area.  Its a very tight location.

Comment: It seems like the question boils down to the definition of "rigidly supported". What sort of force must the platform be expected to withstand? The structure you describe will weigh several hundred pounds and should be fairly stable, though I'm not sure how the plywood box ties to the deck blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Where I could not go deep enough I ran rigid ~5” below the surface then used a 5 gallon bucket brought up the pipe from the bottom to a bell box went back out to the next one. I  filled the bucket with concrete. That gives more than 1 cu ft of concrete and was allowed by my AHJ. The bell box’s I used had 3 openings 2 on the bottom for in and out and one on top for a light, every other one I put a receptacle on the box. I cut the bottom out of the bucket but did press the bucket into the gravel I had there. If I do it again I would put the top of the plastic bucket down in the gravel not the bottom of the bucket as they are slightly tapered and getting the bucket off was a pain with the taper going the right way it would have been much easier but if you have a few extra 5 gallon buckets this was allowed in my jurisdiction as sufficient I think 1 cu ft of concrete was the minimum.